# Show square-integrable functions are closed over addition

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces

I'm working on an exercise to better-understand vector spaces. In particular, I'm trying to show that the space of square-integrable real-valued functions $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under addition.

$$
\mathcal{F} = \{ f ~|~ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ~,~ \int^\infty_{-\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty \}
$$

Proof: Take two functions $f, g \in \mathcal{F}$ and let $h = f + g$.

We then have;

\begin{align}
\int^\infty_{-\infty} |h(x)|^2 dx &= \int^\infty_{-\infty} |f(x) + g(x)|^2 dx 
\\
&\le \int^\infty_{-\infty} \left(|f(x)| + |g(x)|\right)^2 dx 
\\
&\le \int^\infty_{-\infty} |f(x)|^2 + |f(x)||g(x)| + |g(x)|^2 dx
\\
&\le \int^\infty_{-\infty} |f(x)|^2 + \int^\infty_{-\infty} |f(x)||g(x)| + \int^\infty_{-\infty} |g(x)|^2 dx
\end{align}

By definition, the first and last terms are finite, as $f, g \in \mathcal{F}$. How can I show that the middle term is also finite (and thus that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under addition?).

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means ?

Comment: The line $\int |f(x) + g(x)|^2 dx = \int (|f(x)| + |g(x)|)^2 dx$ is not accurate, for example take $g(x) = -f(x)$. It should be an inequality.

Comment: Triangle inequality?

Comment: @twnly thank you - I updated the working as per your suggestion.

Comment: @Cuhrazatee - using the triangle inequality, I still end up with a $|f(x)||g(x)|$ term, so I have the same problem.

Comment: @Mindlack I don't see how the AM-GM inequality can be used here - are you able to elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @aaronsnoswell: $|f||g| \leq |f|^2+|g|^2$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|a+b|^2 \leq 2(|a|^{2}+|b|^{2})$. Apply this to $a =f(x),b=g(x)$ and integrate.

[$|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$. Now, $(|a|-|b|)^{2} \geq 0$. Expanding this we get $|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}-2|a||b| \geq 0$. In other words $2|a||b|\leq |a|^{2}+|b|^{2}$. Adding $|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}$ to both sides we get $2|a||b|+ |a|^{2}+|b|^{2} \leq 2|a|^{2}+2|b|^{2}$. This gives $|a+b|^{2}\leq (|a|+|b|)^{2}=2|a||b|+ |a|^{2}+|b|^{2} \leq 2|a|^{2}+2|b|^{2}$].

Comment: Thank you - I can see that substituting this inequality makes the remainder of the proof straight forward. I wasn't aware of this inequality though - does it have a name? Are you able to provide a link to some more information or sketch a proof of this inequality? Thank you!

Comment: $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$Note that for all $z,w\in \C$, we have $$\begin{align*}|z+w|^2 &= (z+w)(\overline{z} + \overline{w}) \\ &= z\overline{z} + w\overline{w} + \left(z\overline{w} + w\overline{z}\right)\\ &= |z|^2 + |w|^2 + 2\,\mathrm{Re}(z\overline{w})\\ &\leq |z|^2 + |w|^2 + 2|z||w|\end{align*}$$ (using $\mathrm{Re}(\zeta) \leq |\zeta|$ for all $\zeta \in \C$). Then use the AM-GM inequality ($2ab\leq a^2 + b^2$ for all $a,b\ge 0$) to finish up.

Comment: It is actually much simpler. Use the fact that $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$ and then the fact that $(|a|-|b|)^{2} \geq 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry @KaviRamaMurthy - I still cant see how those facts lead to the inequality - are you able to spell it out? Not trying to be difficult, just not very good at this...

Comment: @aaronsnoswell I have given the details in my answer.

Comment: @Servaes Very true. But it was not clear to me that the OP was familiar with convexity so I decided to give the  most elementaray proof possible I have not used any theorem at all.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you! I can follow the working now :) Appreciate it muchly!